# Restricted OLS have less variance than OLS?

Tags: regression, least-squares, efficiency, blue

According to [Gauss-Markov Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem), ordinary least squares (OLS) is the best linear unbiased estimator (BLUE). How then can [restricted OLS](http://fedc.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/xplore/tutorials/xegbohtmlnode18.html) have less variance?
Please tell me the reason.

Comment: I proposed an edit to your question. If your edit does not address your question please correct it.

Comment: No entirely sure but if OLS assumption of no correlation not met, but [GLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) correlation assumption met then possibly restricted OLS has the lesser variance.

Comment: Please explain why you think the variance is smaller with the restrictions!

Comment: I suppose the OP thinks so because of the following sentence *"Consequently, the diagonal elements of  $ V(\hat{\beta}_{R})$ (variances of each  $ \hat{\beta}_{Rj}$) are equal to or less than the corresponding elements of  $ V(\hat{\beta})$ (variances of each  $ \hat{\beta}_{j})$. This means that, if the a priori information is correct (as we will show later , in this case  $ \textrm{E}(\hat{\beta}_{R})=\beta)$, the estimator vector  $ \hat{\beta}_{R}$ is more efficient than the OLS estimator."* It's in the reference he linked http://fedc.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/xplore/tutorials/xegbohtmlnode18.html

Answer (score 3):

The main intuition is that restricted OLS are generally biased. So there is a tradeoff between bias and variance: you reduce variance but you allow bias.

- An **example**: suppose that you want to estimate the average height of the people in your state. You may have learned that if you have a random sample (say of 2000 individuals), a "reasonable" estimator is the sample average, which is unbiased. But you have "prophecy" skills and you know for sure that the average of the population is 175cm. Then there is no variance at all, it is zero, which is lower than any estimator you can come up with. But, except if you are a really good prophet (or your cheated with data) it is likely to be biased.
- A more explicit **answer** to your question would be a direct comparison of the variances of the restricted and unrestricted estimator.

$$Var(\beta_u) = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$$

$$Var(\beta_c) = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1} - \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}R'(R(X'X)^{-1}R')^{-1}R(X'X)^{-1}$$

Therefore the variance of the restricted estimator is always weakly smaller than the variance unrestricted estimator, with equality when the restrictions are true.

- **Advanced** : You can see this [early test](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2284027?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) discussing the topic: the condition so that

$MSE(\hat{\beta_u}) - MSE(\hat{\beta_c})$ is positive semidefinite [$\beta_u$ is the unconstrained, $\beta_c$ the constrained estimator]

The condition is met iff $\lambda< 1/2$, where

$$\lambda = \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(R\beta-r)'(R(X'X)^{-1}R')^{-1}(R\beta-r),$$
where $R\beta = r$ is the vector of constraints you impose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think restricted OLS are biased. Look at Hansen's textbook *Econometrics* section 8.4 "Finite sample properties". Theorem 8.2 says CLS estimators are unbiased for $\beta$.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to CV! What about the variance of CLS (which is what the question is asking about)?

Comment: The restricted case is only unbiased when the restriction is true.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X_1 \sim N(\mu_1,1)$ and $X_2 \sim N(\mu_2,1)$. And we want to estimate $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$.

- **Unrestricted case.** We will use $\hat{\mu}_i = X_i$ and the variance of the error will be equal to one.
- **Restricted case.** Let for instance impose the restriction $\mu_1+\mu_2 = 0$ or $\mu_1 = - \mu_2$. Now we will estimate a single parameter $\hat{\mu}  = \frac{X_1-X_2}{2}$ instead (and we can make the relationships $\hat{\mu}_1 = \hat{\mu}$, $\hat{\mu}_2 = -\hat{\mu}$).

  The variance of the estimate will now be equal to $1/2$. Indeed, it is a smaller variance.
- **Restricted case. When the restriction is untrue.** If we do not truly have $\mu_1 = - \mu_2$ then our estimate $\hat{\mu} \sim N(\frac{\mu_1 - \mu_2}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ will be biased and we may have a larger error.

  The restricted case is not unbiased.